# If with number range

Tags: python, if-statement

I work with python.
I am trying to create a column of ones and zeros, yo know the period of the year.

- For weeks [25:47], i want to put 0
- For weeks [48:24], i want to put 1

```
selected['Period']=np.zeros(len(selected.index))
for i in selected['Week']:
    if (25<=i<=47):
        selected['Period']=0
    elif (48<=i>=24):
        selected['Period']=1
```

Week columns has week values of the year (int) created from x.week function (from datetime)
I have tried to expand the condictions, try differetns forms, but it only takes zero value and i can't see the problem.
Thanks!

My idea is to have a column with binary values, and, with a function select the period of the year to work with, or [25,47] period, or [48,24]

To be more clear: [0,24] -> 1 ; [25,47] -> 0 ; [48,52] -> 1.

EDIT:
[data frame for the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Yuw.png)

[output of a part of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnSlE.png)

Comment: Your ranges don't make sense to me.  e.g. should `47` be 0 or 1?

Comment: Check your ranges, bc this doesnt make sense it should be 25 <= i <= 47

Comment: `if (25<=i>=47)` means `if (i >= 25) and (i >= 47):`. I suspect that is not what you want.

Comment: For weeks in 25,47 range (25,26,.....46, 47) i want 0. And 48,24 range (48,49....0...23,24) i want 1

Comment: Wdym? That last comment makes no sense bc those two ranges are 99% the same range.

Comment: Are you missing a minus, should this go from 25 to negative (-47) ????

Comment: i've corrected the <

Comment: My man, how do you go from 48 to 49 (meaning you increment by 1 or add 1) to 0 ???????????????????????????

Comment: My idea is to have a column with binary values, and, with a function select the period of the year to work with, or [25,47] period, or [48,24]

Comment: You dont seem to understand if you go 48 to 49 to 50, 51, 52 you dont get to 0...... 0 is smaller than 48 meaning your ranges mathematically dont make sense. They dont make sense in any regard. And again your last comment [25-47] and [24 - 48] One range is fully within the other range???? is number 30 supposed to be 1 or 0 then???

Comment: To be more clear: [0,24] -> 1 ; [25,47] -> 0 ; [48,52] -> 1.

Comment: "to be more clear" you meant to say "to finally be clear"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selected['Period'] = np.zeros(len(selected.index))
for i in selected['Week']:
    if 0 <=i <= 24:
        selected['Period'] = 1
    elif 25 <=i <= 47:
        selected['Period'] = 0
    elif 48 <=i <= 52:
        selected['Period'] = 1
```

After some time discussing this in the comments, I assume this is what you want.

Comment: I expected that it'll work but not, it put in all the col. a '1', as you can see in the first post (edited)

Comment: @aandoni Can you put in the question how the columns look, as in show what the values are.

Comment: i did It with your if conditions but in the for loop adding the Index and using .loc inside

Answer (score 1):

What about using a simple `else`?

```
selected['Period'] = np.zeros(len(selected.index))
for i in selected['Week']:
    if 25 <=i <= 47:
        selected['Period'] = 0
    else:
        selected['Period'] = 1
```

Comment: The explanation from OP makes zero sense. This is the most logical solution but without some massive editing to the question we wont know what OP wants.

Comment: With this code the period columns is all with '1'

Comment: `selected['Period']` will get the value it is given in the last iteration of the loop. If you want something different you'll have to explain it in the question.

Comment: @Matthias Read the comments of the question.